# ASP.NET MVC Checkbox Set Checked with JQuery and Metronic

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have a form I'm building for an asp.net mvc project and I have checkboxes with one at the top that basically is suppose to be a 'select all' for the ones below. The JQuery should be pretty simple to do this... however, it doesn't work.

JQuery:

```
$("#SelectAll").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#Option1').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#Option1').prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

I've tried various ways to select the checkboxes:

```
$('#Option1').attr('checked', true);

$('input[type="checkbox"][id="Option1"]').attr("checked", true);
```

None of this works. I click the 'select all' checkbox and the other ones don't change at all.

Also, I am using Bootstrap for the view and JQuery Validation for the form, but not on the checkboxes.

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Option1:</label>
    <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:7px;">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Option1, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Forgot to add that I'm using the Metronic template.

Comment: If you look at your generated HTML, you will see that the ID of your checkbox is not `Option1` but rather `Options`.  Option1 is simply your label.  The `Html.CheckBoxFor` will render a checkbox with the name of the model property that you gave the helper.

Comment: Sorry about that. It should have been model.Option1. I've looked at the rendered html and the id and name match what I have in the asp.net and jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of checkbox "Option1" checked property after you select all. Something like this:

$('#Option1').prop('checked');

Run this in the console and see what is the value of checked property after select all. This will give you an idea what is going on. Whether your code is actually working or not.

Since you said you are using bootstap I must ask you if you are using some theme? Usually themes have preinstalled plugins like jQuery uniform etc. for the form controls which render differently than a normal checkbox control. So even if you update the checked property of your control it still does not render it until you update it using the plugin that rendered it.

Edit:
OP commented that he is using Metronic. So my idea was right that he is using some theme which is not rendering the checkbox. The solution is to call the Metronic.updateUniform($(checkbox)); after updating the checked property for each checkbox on selectAll.

Comment: I sortof felt like that might be the problem. The code isn't actually accurate (the names and id's of things). I'm working on my company's admin dashboard and we are using Metronic as the template  so I'm not sure what it uses besides Bootstrap, JQuery and JQuery UI.

Comment: So I tried your suggestion and clicking the 'select all' checkbox changed the value of one of them to true and then back to false... but it doesn't show the checked status visually in the checkbox.

Comment: If you are using Metronic you should call Metronic.updateUniform function after you change the checked property.

Comment: Metronic has javascript functions? I thought it was just css.... do you mean the Angular JS version? We're not using that.

Comment: Yes it has Javascript functions. Metronic uses jQuery uniform plugin to render your checkbox.

`code`
$("#SelectAll").change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('#Option1').prop('checked', true);
    }
    else {
        $('#Option1').prop('checked', false);
    }

    Metronic.updateUniform($("#Option1"));
});
`code`

Comment: hmm.... it's saying Metronic isn't defined. Maybe I don't have the right files included.

Comment: See if you have Metronic.js

Comment: Actually, I found it!!! For some reason we have app.js instead of Metronic.js, but the function was in there! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$("#SelectAll").click(function () {
    if ($(this)[0].checked) {
       $('input[type="checkbox"][name*="option"]').attr('checked', true);
    }
    else {
       $('input[type="checkbox"][name*="option"]').attr('checked', false);
    }
});
```

Comment: That does not work in my case. I've put alerts in the if statements and they pop up so it's not the if. btw, what does the * do in name*="option"?

Comment: It mean name contains option

Answer (score 0):

Below is a working sample (with 3 random "Option" checkboxes) for selecting all checkboxes with jQuery.  This sample assumes you are using jQuery 1.6 or higher.  Since this is similar to your code, I would assume that your markup is incorrect or that you have some other type of JavaScript error that we cannot see here.  Also, the code has been simplified to set all checkboxes with a class of "form-control" to be checked or not checked based on the "checked" status of the SelectAll checkbox.

```js
    $(function(){
      $("#SelectAll").on("change", function(){
        $("input[type=checkbox][class=form-control]").prop("checked", $(this).is(":checked"));     
        });      
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    Change All <input type="checkbox" id="SelectAll"/><br/><br/>

    Option1: <input type="checkbox" id="Option1" class="form-control"/><br/>
    Option2: <input type="checkbox" id="Option2" class="form-control"/><br/>
    Option3: <input type="checkbox" id="Option3" class="form-control"/><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using metronic, you should add this line after the prop:

```
$.uniform.update();
```